# SOAP decoding unknown documentstream response in python

Tags: python, soap

For the life of me I can't figure this out.

I created a simple soap request to a webserver that requests a document stream.

I get the following response

```
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
#status#    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Language    en-US
Date    Fri, 11 Dec 2018 19:45:17 GMT
X-Powered-By    Servlet/3.0
Content-Type    text/xml; charset=UTF-8

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <a:RetrieveCompanyResponse xmlns:a="http://somewebservice.company.morecompany.com/">
            <documentStream>AF3xQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA...</documentstream>
        <a:RetrieveCompanyResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

documentStream contains a lot more characters than shown.

I understand that I'm supposed to do some type of base64 decoding, but everytime I try to I get some garbage value like below.

```
base64.decodestring('AF3xQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA').decode('ISO-8859-1')
>>>  ]ñ@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like it's binary data (which would explain why it's base64-encoded).  You need to find out what's supposed to be so you can decode it.  It could be a compressed file of some kind, or a proprietary format like old Word docs.

Comment: Thanks. After I find out what the file is supposed to be, would I just decode it and redirect the stream to write to an empty file?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found my answer. As snakecharmerb suggested it is likely due to it being old document format. I found out the format by doing some more digging. Heres a sample code that deciphers my above problem.

```
import base64
import codecs

tmp_str = b'AF3xQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA'
# convert to base64 and then decode using IBM500
ascii_txt = codecs.decode(base64.b64decode(tmp_str), 'cp500')
utf8Str = ascii_txt.encode('utf-8')

print utf8Str
```

The printed string looks like this

```
 )1
```

Heres the document that helped me

https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Hopefully this helps somebody.